# Nested callback issue

Tags: javascript, callback

I know that it is a really basic question but I am stuck on it.
I would be realyy thankful if anyone could help me with it.
I want to create a nested callback. I have two functions whatDoYouWantToEat and whatDoYouWantToDrink
How can I convert whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", whatDoYouWantToDrink) to see "I want tea" in concole.

```
function whatDoYouWantToEat(a, b, callback) {
  console.log(a, b);
  callback();
}

function whatDoYouWantToDrink(c) {
  console.log("I want " + c);
}

whatDoYouWantToDrink("tea");
whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", whatDoYouWantToDrink);
```

Comment: `whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", () => whatDoYouWantToDrink("tea"));`

Comment: or `whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", whatDoYouWantToDrink.bind(this, "tea"))`

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: And if I wanted to add another function:
...
function whatDoYouWantToDrink(c, callback) {
  console.log("I want " + c);
  callback();
}

function whatForDessert(d) {
  console.log("I would like " + d);
}

whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", () => whatDoYouWantToDrink("tea"));

**whatDoYouWantToEat("cake", "apple", () => whatDoYouWantToDrink("tea", () => whatForDessert("ice-cream"))
);**
I get an error Callback is not a function.

Comment: Chris G is there a chance that you could tell me what am I doung wrong here